# Modify nginx.conf to support n number of wildfly instances

Tags: nginx, docker, jenkins

I am implementing docker solution using Jenkins and Docker.

At runtime, it ll be decided how many wildfly instances to start in separate docker containers. All these instances are load balanced using Nginx.

Currently my nginx.conf is supporting 3 containers. I want to add n number of machines under app-service list. Is there any way to provision this in nginx? Here is my nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 4;
events { worker_connections 1024; }
http {
    upstream app-service {

          least_conn;
          server appA:8080;
          server appB:8080;
          server appC:8080 
    }

    server {
          listen 80;
          listen 443 default ssl;

          server_name appserver.domain.com;

        # Add Certificate
          #added my certs herey

          # optimization SSL code
          # ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;                                   
      location / {
            proxy_pass http://app-service;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
          }
    }
```

}

```
I can modify app-server list after starting all the instances but I am looking for a clean solution.
```

Currently I have created only one 'server' in the nginx.conf file and in QA or Production, I will be able to separate port 80 and 443